# Pic18F67K40 unable to read 7940 RTCC over I2C

Tags: pic, i2c, mplabx

I'm trying to integrate the MCP7940N RTCC into my design. The MCU is the PIC18F67K40 and I'm using I2C to communicate. I created a new starter project to make sure that it works there before I add to my larger design. My IDE is MPLab X v5.4 with MCC 4.02, core v5.0.2. I can't get even this basic project to communicate correctly, I believe the problem is with the timing of the pulses. For this prototype I'm using the Explorer 8 and Mikroe's RTC6 Click board. I started with the RTC Example and I2CSimple Foundation Service. The [RTCC Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005010H.pdf) says it can handle I2C clock up to 400 kHz.

```
Initialization
...
    #pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // External Oscillator mode Selection bits->Oscillator not enabled
    #pragma config RSTOSC = HFINTOSC_64MHZ 
...
    SSP1CLKPPS = 0x13;   //RC3->MSSP1:SCL1;    
    RC3PPS = 0x19;   //RC3->MSSP1:SCL1;    
    RC5PPS = 0x1A;   //RC5->MSSP1:SDA1;    
    SSP1DATPPS = 0x15;   //RC5->MSSP1:SDA1;   
...
    SSP1STAT = 0x80;
    SSP1CON1 = 0x18;
    SSP1CON2 = 0x00;
    SSP1ADD  = 0x03;
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPEN = 0;
...
    // NOSC HFINTOSC; NDIV 1; 
    OSCCON1 = 0x60;
    // CSWHOLD may proceed; SOSCPWR Low power; 
    OSCCON3 = 0x00;
    // MFOEN disabled; LFOEN disabled; ADOEN disabled; SOSCEN disabled; EXTOEN disabled; HFOEN disabled; 
    OSCEN = 0x00;
    // HFFRQ 64_MHz; 
    OSCFRQ = 0x08;
    // TUN 0; 
    OSCTUNE = 0x00;
```

I can open the I2C channel just find, but when I try to read a register on the RTCC it hangs waiting for
`PIR3bits.SSP1IF` to be set but it never is. I'm using MCC to generate the RTC and I2C code for me. Thank you.

**Edit 1**:
Here is the schematic for the RTC click board.
[image]

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope, a logic analyzer, or even a logic probe?  I2C always gives me fits, it's always because I've done something stupid, and I always resolve it by looking at the lines on a scope in astonishment, looking at my code or my schematic, and then smacking my forehead and thinking "dumbass!"

Comment: Speaking of which -- a schematic would help.  You *do* have pullups, right?

Comment: I haven’t actually built the circuit myself. I’m using the RTC 6 click and the explorer 8 with the PIM for my MCU.

Comment: Explorer 8. https://www.microchip.com/promo/explorer-8-development-board & RTC 6 https://www.mikroe.com/rtc6-click

Comment: The RTC chips are different if I'm not mistaken. You are targeting **MCP7940N**, whereas the RTC 6 click has **MCP79410** (whether they are too dissimilar I don't know, but they may have different I²C addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally got it working. Had to buy a logic analyzer and make a few changes, but it seems to be working now. First I changed my clock settings to this:

[image]
Second I changed the SDA line from RC5 to RC4 to match what the RTC6 click was expecting. I probably didn't need to, but I wrote my own I2C logic for a basic write & read because the MCC generated code was way too complicated for me to follow.

Here is the I2C.h

```
#ifndef I2C
#define I2C

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void I2C_Initialize(void);
void I2C_Start();
void I2C_Write(uint8_t address, uint8_t reg, uint8_t data);
uint8_t I2C_Read(uint8_t address, uint8_t reg);
void I2C_Stop();

#endif
```

and the I2C.c file. I'm including the mcc.h file just so I can use the __delay_ms function in my write code.

```
#include "I2C.h"
#include "./mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"

void I2C_Initialize(){
    SSP1STAT = 0x80;
    SSP1CON1 = 0x08;
    SSP1CON2 = 0x00;
    SSP1ADD  = 0x06;
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPEN = 0;
}

void I2C_Start(){
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPEN = 1;
    SSP1CON2bits.SEN = 1;
    while(SSP1CON2bits.SEN);
    PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
}

void I2C_Write(uint8_t address, uint8_t reg, uint8_t data){
    I2C_Start();
    SSP1BUF = (address << 1);//left shift 1 bit to clear 7th bit (7th bit == 0 for write)
    while(!PIR3bits.SSP1IF);
    PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
    if(SSP1CON2bits.ACKSTAT){
        SSP1CON2bits.PEN = 1;
        while(SSP1CON2bits.PEN);
        return;
    }
    
    SSP1BUF = reg;
    while(!PIR3bits.SSP1IF);
    PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
    if(SSP1CON2bits.ACKSTAT){
        SSP1CON2bits.PEN = 1;
        while(SSP1CON2bits.PEN);
        return;
    }
    
    SSP1BUF = data;
    while(!PIR3bits.SSP1IF);
    PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
    __delay_ms(5);
    I2C_Stop();
}

uint8_t I2C_Read(uint8_t address, uint8_t reg){
    I2C_Start();
    uint8_t data;
    
    SSP1BUF = (address << 1);//left shift 1 bit to clear 7th bit (7th bit == 0 for write)
    while(!PIR3bits.SSP1IF);
    PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
    if(SSP1CON2bits.ACKSTAT){
        SSP1CON2bits.PEN = 1;
        while(SSP1CON2bits.PEN);
        return (0xFF);
    }
    
    SSP1BUF = reg;
    while(!PIR3bits.SSP1IF);
    PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
    if(SSP1CON2bits.ACKSTAT){
        SSP1CON2bits.PEN = 1;
        while(SSP1CON2bits.PEN);
        return (0xFF);
    }
    
    SSP1CON2bits.RSEN = 1;
    while(SSP1CON2bits.RSEN);
    PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
    
    address = (address << 1); //shift left 1 bit to clear 7th bit
    address |= 0x01; //bitwise OR to set 7th bit a 1 (read is 1))    
    SSP1BUF = address;
    while(!PIR3bits.SSP1IF);
    PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
    if(SSP1CON2bits.ACKSTAT){
        SSP1CON2bits.PEN = 1;
        while(SSP1CON2bits.PEN);
        return (0xFF);
    }
    SSP1CON2bits.RCEN = 1;    
    while(!SSP1STATbits.BF);
    data = SSP1BUF;
    
    SSP1CON2bits.ACKDT = 1;
    SSP1CON2bits.ACKEN = 1;
    while(SSP1CON2bits.ACKEN);
        
    I2C_Stop();
    
    return data;
}

void I2C_Stop(){
    SSP1CON2bits.PEN = 0;
    while(SSP1CON2bits.PEN);
    SSP1CON1bits.SSPEN = 0;
    SSP1CON2bits.RCEN = 0;
}
```

All combined I now see this in my logic analyzer.
[image: I2C Write]
[image: I2C Read]

Hope this helps someone else. Here is the link to my [github for this project](https://github.com/swernimo/clock)